# Can active sensor data be fed into an Autodesk Inventor Simulation?

Tags: sensors, kinematics

I'd like to drive the position of various components within a virtual assembly based on sensor data being collected in real time from an external device. Does Inventor support such a setup?

The goal is to match the relative movements of the components on screen to the real-world counterpart. For example, a absolute rotary encoder records the current angle of a physical joint and the virtual joint is rotated to match. Is this feasible?

My past searches for information on this have turned up empty; perhaps because I'm using the wrong search terms. Most results point to irrelevant mechanical stress simulations.